# Ruby on Rails, Michael Hartl;s Tutorial chapter 6.31

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I got two tests that are failing in my application. I see that the problem is with the user's ID but I don't know how to solve it.

```
1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
 Failure/Error: it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }

   expected: #<User id: 2, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2014-08-09 17:17:22", updated_at: "2014-08-09 17:17:22", password_digest: "$2a$04$kQk6PkLu3X6rbTPiDDPce.zy6VYtAZ2rxchGLSP27VaG...">
        got: #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$dccvbYxyrCa2M1LjxmwQqOBEEhYLNKrFmUh0GlAxH1bH...">

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -#<User id: 2, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2014-08-09 17:17:22", updated_at: "2014-08-09 17:17:22", password_digest: "$2a$04$kQk6PkLu3X6rbTPiDDPce.zy6VYtAZ2rxchGLSP27VaG...">
   +#<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$dccvbYxyrCa2M1LjxmwQqOBEEhYLNKrFmUh0GlAxH1bH...">

 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:102:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 2) User email address with mixed case should be saved as all lower-case
 Failure/Error: expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find User without an ID
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:72:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my user_spec.rb file :

```
describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject {@user}

  it {should respond_to(:name)}
  it {should respond_to(:email)}
  it {should respond_to(:password_digest)}
  it {should respond_to(:password)}
  it {should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}
  it {should respond_to(:authenticate)}



  describe "When name is not present" do
    before {@user.name = " "}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "When email is not present" do
    before {@user.email = " "}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end 

  describe "When name is too long" do
    before {@user.name = "a"*51}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
      foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "email address with mixed case" do
    let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

    it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
      @user.email = mixed_case_email
      @user.save
      expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
    end
  end

  #PASSWORD

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")

      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

And the user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: You can't call `@user.reload` if user hadn't been saved. That's the reason of the error "Could't find User without and ID".

Comment: What happens if you require 'spec_helper' at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

to

```
  @user = User.create(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
```

new just creates a model but doesnt save it to DB whereas
create creates the model AND saves it to DB

other option is to use save

```
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                         password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
@user.save
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue here. I can't reproduce Adrian's test failures when I transplant his code into my version of the app; and in both mine and his only `new` is used.

Comment: thanks for your advice, @ob264
your advices were not letting me pass the tests.
The sneaky way I used to pass the tests was to simplify them,

Answer (score 0):

(For the 2º test) You have to save the user in a before block

```
describe "email address with mixed case" do
  let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

  before do
    @user.email = mixed_case_email
    @user.save
  end

  it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
  end
end
```

That is the problem which causes "Couldn't find User without an ID"

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
```

this line is wrong, correct one is:

```
specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be false }
```